# Getting NoMethodError - undefined method even though the method doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sinatra

I have a Sinatra app where when I visit a url, it's trying to retrieve data from the previous code somehow. For ex, previously Users controller had some code to retrieve users and currently I have deleted everything. It still gives the below error:

```
NoMethodError at /testers/v1/users
undefined method `default_user_id'
```

I have even removed `default_user_id' from the model, schema, migration and doesn't appear in the table in Postgres.

schema.rb:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "code", limit: 10, null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
end
```

controller:

```
module Testers
  module V1
    class UsersController
      get '/' do
        success(200, 'result')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: So is that method being called in the view or controller?  Can you share the view code and the controller code?

Comment: @RockwellRice Sorry the above shared code is schema and container. It doesn't have a view, it's just an API

Comment: oh duh, I guess the `v1` could have been a hint, I assume you have just done a directory wide search for that method to see where it could be sticking around?

Comment: @RockwellRice Strangely it doesn't seem to be there anywhere in the repo.

Comment: So you are sure the changes have been deployed, or whatever ENV you are working in, you are sure the updated code is active?

Comment: @RockwellRice I'm running it locally. If I make any change in pgadmin in a table, then I do see the updated data when I visit an endpoint for the other controllers. But not for this. It seems it is serving me a cached version and trying to retrieve the data from the previous code

Comment: Is it possible that the method is in a gem?  Whenever I get an error like this and can't find it in a directory wide search I usually suspect a gem of containing it.  Pretty rare scenario for sure, and likely not the answer, but without seeing the whole picture it seems worth investigating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed to work after resetting the database `db:reset`